# While asking new question, what is the criteria for a tag to become visible as 'suggested tag'?

Tags: support, tags, suggested-tags

I  have recently wrote a few questions for *Gerrit code review system* and with each question being written, I could clearly see, that only [git](/questions/tagged/git) tag appears among *suggested tags*:

> [image]

The [gerrit](/questions/tagged/gerrit) tag has now over 400 questions and I put that string in many places in my question, but even though it doesn't appeared as *suggested tag*.

So: **what conditions must a tag meet to become visible among suggested tags**?

Additional information:

1. For past five-six questions about Gerrit, [git](/questions/tagged/git) was the only tag that was visible among suggested tags. A few minutes ago, I've asked another question about Gerrit, and this time I saw whole bunch of suggested tags, including: [git](/questions/tagged/git), [svn](/questions/tagged/svn), [merge](/questions/tagged/merge), [github](/questions/tagged/github), and [version-control](/questions/tagged/version-control), though neither GitHub nor SVN **haven't been mentioned even an once in my question**.
2. As in above, just added new question, this time for *Notepad++* and [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) tag wasn't among *suggested*, though it has **1800+** questions tagged and though this name is mentioned few times in question body; on contrary, [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [css](/questions/tagged/css) tags were suggested, though there isn't even a trace of them in question body.

This case (my question) becomes more and more interesting...

Comment: My best guess it minimum questions threshold bigger than 400, maybe 1000 or 2000. Anyway, you wrote "though neither GitHub nor ____ haven't been mentioned even an once in my question" - nor what?

Comment: Nor "SVN", sorry for missing that out (not enough coffee in my body). Yes, my question would qualify (unfortunately) as full duplicate of the one mentioned, by you, if not for the strange (?) behavior of suggesting tags nearly-completely irrelevant to what is being asked. So, either any of us rephrase question to ask only about that, or you should close it as direct duplicate (again, unfortunately, sorry for not catching that out).

Comment: Well, that other one was talking only about the feature here in Meta before it was released to the whole network... let's see what others think.